# Change the color of the placeholder of a disabled Input from the general theme Mui

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-ui, placeholder

I need to change the color of the placeholder text of a disabled input from the general theme of my app.

I want to change the color of the placeholder of a disabled input from the theme (this is a behavior I want to have everywhere in my application). I tried to do this (see theme.tsx file in codesandbox) by targetting **MuiFormControl**, **MuiInputBase** and **MuiInput** components but I can't reach their placeholder. Yet when I add the field backgroundColor in my theme to see what I target, the backgroundColor changes well as I ask so I think I am in the right place.

I put my code in a codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/placeholder-disabled-input-97gdl5?file=/src/theme.js

If I modify the css directly from the web console at execution I manage to change the color of the placeholder: (see screenshot 1 and 2)

[placeholder unmodified despite custom theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntEgI.jpg)

[placeholder modified from web console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3IWo.jpg)

As you can see in the codesandbox, I have no problem to target the placeholder if it is not deactivated but I can not access the placeholder if the component is deactivated, how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using CSS selectors in the style overrides: Instead of using CSS selectors like **.MuiInput-input**, it's recommended to use the **classes** prop provided by MUI to directly apply custom class names to the component.

```js
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiInput: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          "& input::placeholder": {
            color: "grey",
          },
          "&.Mui-disabled input::placeholder": {
            WebkitTextFillColor: "grey",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback, your way of doing things is clearly better than mine, I'll be able to redo a good part of my theme with this practice :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to target **-webkit-text-fill-color** in **.Mui-disabled** class in **.MuiInput-input**. Here my final MuiInput theme for placeholder part:

```
const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
        MuiInput: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {=
                    ".MuiInput-input": {
                        "&::placeholder": {
                            color: GREY,
                        },

                        "&.Mui-disabled": {
                            "&::placeholder": {
                                "-webkit-text-fill-color": GREY,
                            },
                        },
                    },=
                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```